# different versions of admin-on-rest confusing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

Most likely this question is to maintainers.

I work with stable version of admin on rest.  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/admin-on-rest)

Now the latest is 1.3.4.

The main branch of project-repository is updating only with fixes last time. As I understand, maintainers are working on features only with next branch: https://www.npmjs.com/package/admin-on-rest-next.

But as I see there is other project in npm called 'react-admin': https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-admin.

I am confused about this version because in repository we see that it is deprecated. We see that we should use admin-on-rest. But if I go to admin-on-rest-next branch, in docs we see info about react-admin! It is deprecated, but it's docs in next branch. It's not clear.

And other question to maintainers: if I plan work with my admin-on-rest project for long time in future,which version should I look at now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is understandable.

Originally, we named our project `admin-on-rest` because:

- We were using REST only
- The name `react-admin` was already taken

However, with the advent of graphql, we worked on making it compatible with any backend. The name `admin-on-rest` was therefor confusing. We reached for the author of `react-admin` and he agreed to give us the name.

So, in a nutshell, `admin-on-rest` and `react-admin` are the same project:

`admin-on-rest` is the first version of our project.
`react-admin` is the second version.

We will only release bug fixes and backward compatible new features on `admin-on-rest` (v1) and we are actively working on `react-admin` (v2) which uses Material UI v1 (currently in beta).

`react-admin` has been released as beta too:

`npm install react-admin@2.0.0-beta2`

All addons packages have been renamed accordingly from `aor-XXX` to `ra-XXX`. Please read the upgrade guide in the `next` branch.

`react-admin` has been published ! https://marmelab.com/react-admin/

Comment: Glad it helps :) Can you mark your question as answered ?

Comment: @Gildas Thanks, but things are still confusing, where is the new documentation for example? If you hit this: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/   We get a 404.

Comment: We have not yet published the documentation on a public site. You'll have to explore the `docs` folder on the github repository.

Comment: react-admin is not officially published, that's why you can't find the doc online anywhere else than GitHub.
We don't recommend using react-admin in production yet - please give use another week to iron out the edges and publish it.